# How to view a doc file in ROR carrierwave

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

How can I view contents of a doc file in carrierwave in a new link?
For example:

```
<a href="<%= @post.attachment_url %>" target="_blank">
  <button type="button" class="btn6 btn-primary4">View Attached</button>
</a>
```

for PDF and Image it's working fine.

Comment: Is this really a carrierwave / Ruby question? Seems like your browser just cannot display doc files. You might have to install a plugin.

Comment: yeah but the requirement is like that.So do you have any other solutions?

Comment: What are your requirements exactly?

Comment: I am uploading doc file as an attachment.They want to view the attachment in a new tab without downloading it.